# Auto Full Screen for FLV?

Tags: html, flash, flv

I have my own player that I use to play flv files (link is below).

If autoStart=true is for auto play, is there anything for auto fullscreen?

http://player.longtailvideo.com/player.swf?file=http://content.bitsontherun.com/videos/bkaovAYt-364766.mp4&autoStart=true&allowfullscreen=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Flash doesn't allow swfs to go to fullscreen without user interaction (to reduce the risk of misleading the user about what the state of their desktop is).